# caret XGBtree with sparse matrix

Tags: r, r-caret

I'm trying to pass a sparse matrix to caret to train with xgb. Apparently this can be done e.g.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(caret)
library(Matrix)

miris <- select(iris, -Species) %>% as.matrix
sparse_miris <- as(miris, "dgCMatrix")

# sparse matrix
xgb_sparse <- train(x = sparse_miris, y = iris$Species,
                method = "xgbTree", 
                trControl = trainControl(method = "cv", classProbs = TRUE))
```

This computes and returns a model xgb_sparse.

When I try this on my real data I get a repeating error on each nround:

```
Error in as.character(x) : 
  cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'character'
```

My real data are over 1M records and I've been unsuccessful in recreating based on a shareable smaller sample of the data. I'm hoping that I can describe my data as best I can and that someone may recognise this error.

```
# make a sparse matrix for xgb
predictors_sparse <- select(training_data, -c(id, cad, cluster)) %>% as.matrix %>% as("dgCMatrix")

> str(predictors_sparse)
Formal class 'dgCMatrix' [package "Matrix"] with 6 slots
  ..@ i       : int [1:1474634] 47 51 268 360 561 902 1007 1258 1391 1402 ...
  ..@ p       : int [1:96] 0 8044 19465 68596 90202 135268 177588 199513 208843 236602 ...
  ..@ Dim     : int [1:2] 1000000 95
  ..@ Dimnames:List of 2
  .. ..$ : chr [1:1000000] "846520" "2320473" "1203874" "2599268" ...
  .. ..$ : chr [1:95] "patrol" "investig" "assault" "alarm" ...
  ..@ x       : num [1:1474634] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 ...
  ..@ factors : list()

> str(training_data$cluster)
 Factor w/ 64 levels "cluster1","cluster10",..: 23 23 23 43 23 23 38 15 23 13 ...
> length(training_data$cluster)
[1] 1000000
```

So I pass to train a sparse matrix with 1M observations as x and for y training_data$cluster which is a factor variable of length 1M.

```
mod_xgb <- train(
  x = predictors_sparse, y = training_data$cluster,
  method = "xgbTree",
  trControl = train_control,
  na.action = na.pass,
  tuneGrid = xgb_grid,
  summaryFunction = "Kappa"
)
```

I don't think it's necessary to paste my train_control or tuneGrid objects but please let me know I can paste them here if asked.

I really want to share example data but am unable to replicate on a sample, only on the full data of 1M.

I'm pretty sure the data I pass are complete with no NA values, I checked before creating variable `predictors_sparse`.

Does the error look familiar to anyone within the context of training a model in caret?

```
Error in as.character(x) : 
      cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'character'
```

Comment: How many levels are there in `training_data$cluster` and did you find anything unusual in the levels wrt to `iris$Species`.  Also, try to run this on a smaller subset of data and check if this returns the same error

Comment: H @akrun. 64 levels ```> str(training_data$cluster)
 Factor w/ 64 levels "cluster1","cluster10",..: 8 31 48 23 43 30 23 23 23 8 ...
> length(unique(training_data$cluster))
[1] 64```

Comment: I tried on a 1k sample and got an error ```Error: One or more factor levels in the outcome has no data: 'cluster24', 'cluster68'
```. Guess all the levels make it tricky to isolate the issue. Do you suspect the levels might be part of the issue?

Comment: Possibly, you need `droplevels` to remove those unused levels that are not in the subset i.e.`droplevels(training_datasubset$cluster)`

Comment: I noticed that you are using `miris` instead of `sparse_miris`

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that I was using miris not sparse_miris. Actually, now that I've corrected caret with xgb does not appear to take a sparse matrix "Warning message:
In train.default(x = sparse_miris, y = iris$Species, method = "xgbTree",  :
  The training data could not be converted to a data frame for saving"